# Where do you edit the MySQL config?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, lamp, xampp

Hi I am looking to change the minimum amount of characters MySQL needs to do a full text search and I can't seem to find that file. The code I am looking to paste in is
ft_min_word_len=3
What file do I paste this in on lampp Ubuntu and then do I save and restart the server?

Thank you
I am a noob so please do a simple explanation! :)

Comment: Why have you tagged this `xampp`? How did you install MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly remember where is it, but the file you want to change is : my.cnf. Most of the time he is located in /etc/my.cnf or /etc/mysql/my.cnf or directly in you datadir. Put this parameter below [mysqld] and restart the service.

Edit : Maybe here : /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf

Comment: service mysql restart

Comment: `dpkg-query -L mysql` should tell you where the file is (might be mysqld)